# Java String best practices

Tags: java, string, memory

I have 4 String parameter's in Java (from request object)

```
String dd = req.getParameter(dd);
String mm = req.getParameter(mm);
String yyyy = req.getParameter(yyyy);
```

after validating dd,mm,yyyy I am building date
object in 4th String variable by building`String date = dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy;` again in some places i need to replace the date 
format as following,

```
date = yyyy+mm+dd;
date =mm+"/"+dd+"/"+yyyy;  // storing in db need this format
```

How much memory would consume since 4 objects need to pass
till persist in table? Was it costlier memory call? Is there any best practice?
At last howmany string objects would be in Stringpool?

Comment: Don't worry about micromanaging objects like this; managed-memory systems like the JVM are extensively optimized to be able to handle these operations efficiently. Write code in the way that is easiest to read. You might, however, consider using a date formatter instead of manually constructing the string.

Comment: In my point of view, the best practise is use a Calendar/Date.

Comment: For most usecases you can just go this way. You could use StringBuilder for this too, but since you only create the string once, it won't make a big difference

Comment: Put the information into a proper date-representing object as soon as possible, and only create strings (using formats) when there is something to display. In Java 8, use the new `java.time` package. In earlier versions, use `Date` and/or `Calendar` or JodaTime. Do not use strings when saving to database.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, I agree with you while persisting in db i am casting date to Java.util.date object only

Comment: thanks @chrylis as I decided to go with date formatter only. Using SimpleTextFormat.

Comment: @aarav For database access you should be using [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)/[.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) not java.util.Date. The future should bring new JDBC drivers that handle the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is that you should not be worry about micro improvement as other also suggested. May be create a wrapper object e.g. `MyDate` and construct `Date` object once. After that you can use different formatter to format your date.

```
package com.dd;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class MyDate {

    private Date date;

    public MyDate(Request req) {
        int day = req.getParameter("dd");
        int month = req.getParameter("mm");
        int year = req.getParameter("yyyy");
        date = new LocalDate(year, month, day).toDate();
    }

    public String format(String givenFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(givenFormat);
        return sdf.format(date);
    }

}
```

Note - You need to confirm and validate what values you're getting from your request and if they are in same notation as expected by `LocalDate`

Comment: You should not be mixing SimpleDateFormat (used with java.util.Date/.Calendar) with Joda-Time. Joda-Time has its own formatter classes.